# Stuck at transforming simple equation, trying to find $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Would anyone help me transform this equation in order to find $x$?

**Expression:** (assuming all numbers are positive)

$\frac{ax}{a+x}=\frac{b}{c^2}$

I tried:

$\frac{ax}{a+x}=\frac{b}{c^2} \quad \text{/}*(a+x)$

$ax=\frac{b(a+x)}{c^2} \quad \text{/} :a$

$x = \frac{b(a+x)}{c^2a}$

But it's not good enough, because I still have $x$ on both sides of the equation.

P.S: If someone could fix my tags, please do so, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{ax}{a+x}=\frac{b}{c^2}$$
$$ax=\frac{b(a+x)}{c^2}$$
$$ax=\frac{ba}{c^2}+\frac{bx}{c^2}$$
$$ax-\frac{bx}{c^2}=\frac{ba}{c^2}$$
$$x\bigg(a-\frac{b}{c^2}\bigg)=\frac{ba}{c^2}$$
$$x=\frac{ba}{c^2\bigg(a-\frac{b}{c^2}\bigg)}$$
$$x=\frac{ba}{ac^2-b}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the reciprocal.
$\dfrac{ax}{a+x}=\dfrac{b}{c^2}$
becomes
$\dfrac{c^2}{b}
=\dfrac{a+x}{ax}
=\dfrac1{x}+\dfrac1{a}
$
so
$\dfrac{c^2}{b}-\dfrac1{a}
=\dfrac1{x}
$.

The rest should be easy.